# Oracle sql query works in sql developer but not in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have filters in a datatable and when user enters some value it should return a list of results matching that filter. I want it to be case-insensitive.
I create the query string for a prepared statement via Java string concatenation, as in the below:

```
public static List<Logger> getAll(int from, int to, Map<String, Object> filters, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    List<Logger> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    String upit = "Select * from (select m.*,rownum r from (";
    String upitZaFilterISort = "select m.* from eps_stage.MDM_OSB_LOG m";

    try {
        con = DataConnect.getConnection();
        int upper = from + to;

        if (filters.size() > 0) {
            upitZaFilterISort = upitZaFilterISort.concat(" where 1=1");
            Set<String> keys = filters.keySet();

            // To get all key: value
            for (String key : keys) {
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("status") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("mbr")
                        || key.equalsIgnoreCase("pib") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("jmbg")
                        || key.equalsIgnoreCase("poruka_tip") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("aplikacija")
                        || key.equalsIgnoreCase("operacija")) {
                    upitZaFilterISort = upitZaFilterISort.concat(
                            " AND UPPER(" + key.toString() + ") LIKE '" + filters.get(key).toString().toUpperCase() + "%'");
                } 
            }
            }
        }

        String sort = "";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(upit + upitZaFilterISort + ") m ) where r>=? and r<=?");

        ps.setInt(1, from);
        ps.setInt(2, upper);

        System.out.println(upit+ upitZaFilterISort + sort+") m " + ") where r>=? and r<=?");

        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

In this line is a problem:

```
upitZaFilterISort = upitZaFilterISort.concat(
        " AND UPPER(" + key.toString() + ") LIKE '" + filters.get(key).toString().toUpperCase() + "%'");
```

When I use case-sensitive comparison it works:

```
upitZaFilterISort = upitZaFilterISort.concat(
        " AND " + key.toString() + " LIKE '" + filters.get(key).toString() + "%'");
```

After concatenation query:

```
Select * from (select m.*,rownum r from (select m.* from eps_stage.MDM_OSB_LOG m where 1=1 AND UPPER(poruka_tip) LIKE 'V%') m ) where r>=1 and r<=20
```

It returns the expected result when I run it in Oracle SQL Developer, but in my app it returns an empty result set.

Does Java put quotes somewhere I don't expect? I will provide more info if needed.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and any error messages you get.

Comment: Is the argument to `UPPER()` supposed to be a column name or a literal?  If the latter then it needs to be quoted.  Also, if the latter then I'm confused by your claim that you intend to use this for a prepared statement, because in that case you are bypassing the natural, best-practice approach of setting the value via a parameter to the statement instead of via string concatenation.  Among many other things, that would bypass the need to worry about quoting.

Comment: In any case, when it does not work in your app, what actually happens?  Incorrect result?  (Then what did you expect, and why?) Exception thrown? (Then what was the exception message?)  Overall, please provide a [mre] that models the issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's a column name. Case sensitive comparison works perfectly and return desired result, case insensitive returns nothing .. Post edited and more code and explanation added

Comment: I wouldn't know why it works in Sql Developer so on this I would also ask that you add a reproducible example.
In the meantime, I do see a number of practices I'd rather avoid if possible:
1. concatenation in SQL queries (search for "Sql Injection")
2. the ```UPPER``` appears on the left-hand side of the condition but not the right one: I'd put it on both sides, for uniformity
3. building queries in a Java class is something I'd rather avoid as you are mixing two very different languages, reducing overall readability. Externalize your queries if possible.

Comment: Your example contains code that prints the query string to the console.  Are you saying that if you cut & paste that into SQL Developer and run it against the same database, then it produces different results?

Comment: If so, then one possibility is that the behavior of Oracle's `UPPER()` does not exactly match that of Java's `String.toUpperCase()`.  One wouldn't expect that for ASCII-only data, but if you have any other characters in your data then the situation is more complicated.

Comment: I have tried to use upper instead of toUppercase, didnt work. @John Bollinger yes i put same query that i print in console in a sql developer and it works.. it selects desired rows.. so i think that java do something but i can't figure it out

Comment: We don't have enough information to figure it out, @Rattus.  We would need a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  But I do not think the issue is inherent in Java.  It might be in the configuration of your database connections.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

1. Check if the user has all the required privileges to make the statements
2. It may happen that the port has only one open connection. Therefore you can only use java or oracle sql developer. Try disconnecting from sql developer and running your java program. If it doesn't work tell me.

I hope it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Re: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_globalization.htm#CCHIJBCG, section "Changing NLS Parameter Values for All Sessions"

Please check your session settings for NLC_COMP, which may be set to LINGUISTIC.  The link below can get you there in SQL Developer.  If set to LINGUISTIC then your SQL Developer sessions are performing case insensitive searches, possibly explaining differences between the sessions.

Also, concur with Filippo's recomended practices.